# How do I correctly write this if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

Suppose that I get the values for valid, d ,sn from a function that I introduced in my program. Then I pass it through the following if statement in python to output the result.

I want the program to print the following statements:

1. print  `on` if the `sn >= 0` and  `1<d <90`.
2. print `off-right` if the `sn<0`.
3. print `off-left` if the `d>=90`
4. other than that, for anything that is not valid outputs `unknown`.

Here is what I wrote, how do I include d when checking the statement?

```
if valid:
    if sn >= 0 and 1<d <90:
        print(" on ")        
    else:
        print("off")
else:
    print("unknown")
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags, if your question isn't Python 2 specific, don't use the Python 2 tag. *Always* use the generic [python] tag. Python 3 is up to you, but nowadays, Python 3 *is Python*

Comment: for the first case, you can replace `sn >= 0` in your code with exactly what you just wrote in the question: `sn >= 0 and 1<d <90`. literally. https://pythonexamples.org/python-and/

Comment: but what about 2 and 3?

Comment: `elif nextcondtion:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if valid:
   if sn >= 0 and d > 1 and d < 90:
      print(" on ")
   elif sn < 0:
      print("off-right")
   elif d >= 90:
      print("off-left")
else:
   print("unknown")
```

Comment: I think you can simply write `1 < d < 90` in python.

Comment: @Pac0 okay, Ill have to test it and see. Nothing against your comment. Just haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want. But most probably you want to do this i guess?

```
if valid:
    if sn >= 0 and (d>1 and d<90):
        print(" on ")
        
    else:
        if sn<0:
            print("off-right")
        elif d>=90:
            print('off-left')
else:
    print("unknown")
```

This is a self explanatory answer..
If you get confused by 1<d<90 then you can use what i did above